# How to select and select count in one query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have this table:

```
Activity     Date    
reading   12-10-2014
watching  12-10-2014
reading   13-10-2014
reading   12-10-2014
watching  13-10-2014
```

What I want to do is selecting the activity and count the activity number based on date, I want the output will be like this (with condition: where date ='12-10-2014'):

```
Activity   count    date
reading      2    12-10-2014
watching     1    12-10-2014
```

How can I do that?, help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Use GROUP BY: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Activity,COUNT(1) `count`,date
FROM mytable WHERE date='12-10-2014'
GROUP BY date,Activity;
```

or

```
SELECT Activity,COUNT(1) `count`,date
FROM mytable WHERE date='2014-10-12'
GROUP BY date,Activity;
```

Make sure you table has an index on date and Activity

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX date_Activity_ndx (date,Activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select activity, count(activity) as count, date from my_table
where date = '12-10-2014' group by activity;
```

(not sure about your column labels--you may have to adjust for capitalization)